# Display 2D text with freeglut, using OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, glfw, text-rendering

I'm pretty new into this and I'd like to display fixed location 2D texts (like level, life, score etc.) on my game's screen which is basically a 3D game. I have found a few similar questions but still could not figure out the solution for me. I mainly use GLFW for everything but I'd like to use glut for displaying texts. I have a funcion (based on a few other questions I've found here) to try out how it works but I'm not sure how exactly can I make it to actually display because now everything starts but *no text is displayed*, only my 3D world..
Here is my code so far:

```
//includes...
//and other stuff...

void display()
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0.0, WindowWidth, 0.0, WindowHeight);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();

    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0); // Green
    glRasterPos2i(20, 20);

    std::string s = "Some text";
    void* font = GLUT_BITMAP_9_BY_15;

    for (std::string::iterator i = s.begin(); i != s.end(); ++i)
    {
        char c = *i;
        glColor3d(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glutBitmapCharacter(font, c);
    }

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPopMatrix();

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glPopMatrix();
}

int main(void)
{
    // init glfw and set some options...
    glfwInit();

    //also, it seems I need to init glut to use my function too which requires arguments...
    {
        int argc = 1;
        char* argv[1] = { (char*)"Something" };
        glutInit(&argc, argv);
    }

    //creating window...
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(WindowWidth, WindowHeight, "The Maze Game", nullptr, nullptr);

    // QUESTION: should I call the function here or where the game loop is? It doesn't work either way.. :(
    display();

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {

        //doing stuff...

        glfwPollEvents();

        // I have to display text later HERE... where the std::couts are... would be better on screen instead of console..

        if(moved == true) timer = timer - delta;

        std::cout << timer << std::endl; 

        if (win == true || timer <= 0.f)
         {
            if (win == true)
            {
                score++;
            }
            if (timer <= 0.f && life > 0)
            {
                life--;
                if (life == 0)
                {
                    std::cout << "You LOST" << std::endl;
                }
            }
            //...stuff
            timer = mazeTime;
            win = false;
            std::cout << "Score: " << score << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Life: " << life << std::endl;
        }

        // Clear the colorbuffer
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        // etc....
```

Comment: Not sure - it doesn't look that bad. I found a lot of samples in [C++ (Cpp) glutBitmapCharacter Examples](https://cpp.hotexamples.com/examples/-/-/glutBitmapCharacter/cpp-glutbitmapcharacter-function-examples.html). In one of them I found a hint: _CAREFUL! It ASSUMES that lighting is NOT enabled -- if it is, you usually won't see any on-screen text._ (It was example #19.) I also found a hint about depth test (to disable) while I was not sure whether `glBitmap()` (which is used in `glutBitmapCharacter()` is effected by depth tests). However, I think it's worth to check out as well.

Comment: Concerning `glBitmap()` vs. depth tests, I found something else: [OpenGL SuperBible](https://books.google.de/books?id=zbyRyKKMRUIC&pg=PT925&lpg=PT925&dq=%22glbitmap%22+depth+test&source=bl&ots=Rjnh3lHkSP&sig=ACfU3U0VaE-hW0uZyHYhPBZw7ZwL6q7iFg&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjWlviWsPnoAhUksaQKHcyYB34Q6AEwBHoECAsQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22glbitmap%22%20depth%20test&f=false). So, disabling depth test might be worth to be checked as well.

Comment: @Scheff, `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)`  is absolutely required for my world to function properly. With disabling it, it  won't look well. However I tried it but no text's displayed yet either...

Comment: You can enable and disable the depth test between multiple phases in one rendering step. E.g. I often enable depth tests for 3d (surface) rendering and disable depth tests to render HUD (head-up display) for augmented stuff like selection, icons, etc. However, these are just hints I collected from examples I mentioned above... Did you try to disable the lighting just before rendering text?

Comment: FYI: [LearnOpenGL - Text Rendering](https://learnopengl.com/In-Practice/Text-Rendering)

Comment: Sorry, okay, I know what you are talking about and I tried to disable it before and enable it after again but it still does not show anything...

Comment: To be honest, I tried to look up many sites and even my code seems perfect, it simply does not display anything. Does this have anything to do with GLFW? I use that to create the window and put the context in there, I'd only use GLUT for this one simple thing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212265/discussion-between-chuck-and-scheff).